# Exporting calender from share point to Excel

Tags: excel, excel-services, excel-online

When I export calendar from share point to excel, I could only see data for one month (current month) in the excel. But, I want to see the data for complete year in the calendar exported to the excel.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: try to change the view from `Calendar` to `All Items` and then try to export.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly two ways to achieve this if you want to export specific data:

1. Export to Excel and Filter:  You will need to go to the View for All Item.  URL would be something like `..../YourCalendarName/AllItems.aspx`
2. Create a calculated column to extract `Year` for the `Start Time` field and you can create a view based on this field which you can export.